# How to secure apache against a KRACK (or a similar MITM) attack?

Tags: apache2, security, https

In [the video](https://youtu.be/Oh4WURZoR98) posted on his web site www.krackattacks.com security researcher Mathy Vanhoef demonstrated that it is possible to downgrade a HTTPS connection to HTTP and then intercept the logon credentials.

I am running a small https server (Apache, Ubuntu 16.04) and I wold like to configure it in a way that would reject any attempts to downgrade HTTPS requests.

1. How can I verify whether my Apache instance would accept and honour a browser request to downgrade HTTPS to HTTP?
2. How can I re-configure Apache to reject such requests from browsers?
3. Is there a reason not to do (2) above? Supporting users with old browsers is one I can think of, is there something else I am missing?

Comment: HTTPS downgrading is independent of krack. It might be piggybacking off krack, but the two are otherwise unrelated.

Comment: I simply did remove the port forwarding for HTTP requests on my router and only accept HTTPS requests. Before i did lead them onto a self written error page, worked well too but didn't prevent the hacking attempts. And as @muru said, its unrelated and client side patches are already been rolled out on most Linux distributions, I would more worry about maybe unpatched Android Phones and the like.

Comment: @muru - yes, they are unrelated but the KRACK video made it clear that whoever gets into a "man in the middle" position can downgrade https and harvest data that should have been protected.

Comment: @Videonauth  I don't think I will be removing http support - neiterh via router configuration or by reconfiguring Apache.  And unpatched android phones will be around for the years to come.

Comment: @sмurf yes, irrespective of whether it's krack or not. It's the MITM position that matters. The question title is misleading in that respect.

Comment: Guilty as charged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is simply don't allow http only https.

The other option is to use HTTP Strict Transport Security.

You can do this in Apache by adding

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

To your TLS enabled vhost.
You should also be redirecting any requests made on http to https to ensure this sticks.

Comment: Can't disallow http. I will look into Strict-Transport-Security, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Why can't you disallow http?

Comment: Because I have static content that doesn't need https. On second thought I might just move everything on the https vhost and be done with it. That would break old links though...

Comment: Doing that leaves you open to other types of attacks like cookie hijacking. HSTS will inform browsers that they should convert ALL of your http links to https so it would NOT break old links.

Comment: Then leaving http available isn't as much of an issue except that those who opt to use it instead of https are vulnerable to all kinds of attacks but there is no false sense of security